# Angular Reactive Forms - async validator is not working

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have created 2 almost identical async validators.

uniqueTitleValidator - This validates for existing string with a simple array 'titles'

```
titleExist(title: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(title).pipe(
      map((title) => {
        const titles = ['abc', '123'];
        return titles.includes(title);
      })
    );
  }

  uniqueTitleValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      return this.titleExist(control.value).pipe(
        map((exists) => {
          console.log('exists title', exists);
          return exists ? { titleExist: true } : null;
        })
      );
    };
  }
```

uniqueVoucherValidator - This validates for an existing string by retrieving data from FireStore

```
voucherExist(title: string, paymentService: PaymentService): Observable<any> {
    return paymentService.getAllPayment().pipe(
      map((payments) => {
        console.log('payments', payments);
        const payment = payments.find(
          (item: any) =>
            item.data.voucherTitle.toLowerCase() == title.toLowerCase()
        );
        console.log('payment validator', payment);
        return !!payment;
      })
    );
  }

  uniqueVoucherValidator(paymentService: PaymentService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      return this.voucherExist(control.value, paymentService).pipe(
        map((exists) => {
          console.log('exists voucher', exists);
          return exists ? { voucherExist: true } : null;
        })
      );
    };
  }
```

Both works and from the screen shot console - you can see the boolean for 'exists title' and 'exist voucher' are returned correctly. However, only the second validator - uniqueVoucherValidator - the validation error is always reflected as null.

[form.control.voucherTitle.errors is reflecting the correct validation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erTy7.png)

[form.control.voucherTitle.errors is always null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKeQd.png)

Need some advice on what could have caused the uniqueVoucherValidator to always show null.

Comment: Can you please show us how you assign them in your component code, ideally a stackblitz showing the issue you're facing is better

Comment: You didnt show how you use your valdiators.

Answer (score 2):

Since Firebase api has not completed.The form control is still in pending status you can use `take(1)` operator to complete observable manually

```
voucherExist(title: string, paymentService: PaymentService): Observable<any> {
    return paymentService.getAllPayment().pipe(
      map((payments) => {
        console.log('payments', payments);
        const payment = payments.find(
          (item: any) =>
            item.data.voucherTitle.toLowerCase() == title.toLowerCase()
        );
        console.log('payment validator', payment);
        return !!payment;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
```